# accessing parent nodes in same level in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Let's say I have a database schema like this:

```
RowId   ParentId   Name
------ ---------- ------
1       NULL      Level1
2       NULL      Level2
3       1         Leaf1
4       1         Leaf2
5       2         Leaf1
6       3         LeafX
```

Basically, the tree would look as such:

```
Level1
       Leaf1
             LeafX
       Leaf2
Level2
       Leaf1
```

I need to extract all ancestor LEVEL of LeafX in the most efficient and dynamic way.

So it will output: Leaf1, Leaf2, and Leaf1 (of Level2)

How do I do this in T-SQL? Thanks

Comment: Parent nodes *never* are on the same level - they're by definition always one level up from any given node....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you the result you want.

```
;with C as
(
  select T.rowid,
         T.parentid,
         T.name,
         1 as Lvl
  from YourTable as T
  where T.parentid is null
  union all
  select T.rowid,
         T.parentid,
         T.name,
         C.Lvl + 1
  from YourTable as T
    inner join C
       on T.parentid = C.rowid
)
select *
from C
where C.Lvl = (
               select C.lvl-1
               from C
               where C.name = 'LeafX'
              )
```

**Update**
And this might be faster for you. You have to test on your data.

```
declare @Level int;

with C as
(
  select T.rowid,
         T.parentid
  from @t as T
  where T.name = 'LeafX'
  union all
  select T.rowid,
         T.parentid
  from @t as T
    inner join C
       on T.rowid = C.parentid
)
select @Level = count(*) - 1
from C;

with C as
(
  select T.rowid,
         T.parentid,
         T.name,
         1 as Lvl
  from @t as T
  where T.parentid is null
  union all
  select T.rowid,
         T.parentid,
         T.name,
         C.Lvl + 1
  from @t as T
    inner join C
       on T.parentid = C.rowid
  where C.Lvl < @Level
)
select *
from C
where C.Lvl = @Level;
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using with just because I don't like ";" before it :) But in this case it's best solution (if you don't have to read data from really big table)

Comment: @RomanPekar Yes this can be slow on a big table. It will build the tree twice since the CTE `C` is used twice and it will build the entire tree even if the node you are looking for as at a high level. If performance with this is an issue I would try to first find the level of the nodes to look for with a recursive CTE going from `LeafX` and up. Then use that value in a the top-down recursive CTE to terminate the recursive part when the desired level is reached.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few methods to do that. My favourite is to create special table Trees_Parents, where you will store every parent for evere node.
So if have structure like that

```
RowId   ParentId   Name
------ ---------- ------
1       NULL      Level1
2       NULL      Level2
3       1         Leaf1
4       1         Leaf2
5       2         Leaf1
6       3         LeafX
```

your Trees_Parents table will looks like

```
RowId   ParentId
------ ----------
1       1     
2       2     
3       3
3       1        
4       4
4       1        
5       5
5       2        
6       6
6       1
6       3
```

then when you need to retrieve all children you just write

```
select RowID from Trees_Parents where ParentId = 1
```

I'm storing row self in this table to avoid unions, if you don't need it you can write

```
select RowID from Trees_Parents where ParentId = 1 and ParentId <> RowId
```

And for all parents you'll write

```
select ParentId from Trees_Parents where RowId = 6 and ParentId <> RowId
```

You can also store Table_Name in table Trees_Parents so you can use it for different tables

Another way is to write recursive WITH clause, but if your tree is big and it's not changing frequently I think it's better to store parents data in additional table

Comment: i dont quite understand this, how come the RowId repeats the identifiers?

Comment: Well, you put rowId and it's parent into table, and then put rowId and parent's parent into table and so on. I did it with after update/insert/delete trigger on main table.

Base idea is - after inserting data into main table, you scan additional table and get all ParentId where RowId = new recordParentId + you inserting RowId as ParentId

For example, you insert rowId = 1, you put rowId = 1 ParentId = 1 into additional table. ParentId is null, so you do not put it into additional table.
When you put rowId = 3 you insert RowId = 3, ParentId = 3 and then
get all parentId where RowId = 1

Comment: It's a little more comlicated when you need to update and delete records, but after that it works very fast if you have indexes on RowId and ParentId in additional table

Comment: i cant really work on this since the data is already existing. are you suggesting i create a table variable everytime i access the levels?

Comment: You can create table, create trigger and than fill additional table with recalculated data.
I've also added more slow recursive solution to your answer, may be it'll help

Comment: Actually I've understand that I've just didn't read a question :) my solution gives you all parents of node. I will write solution in recursive solution post

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use recursive solution. You need to get all nodes with Depth = Depth of your node - 1

```
declare @Temp table (RowId int, ParentId int, Name nvarchar(128))

insert into @Temp
select 1, null, 'Level1' union all
select 2, null, 'Level2' union all
select 3, 1, 'Leaf1' union all
select 4, 1, 'Leaf2' union all
select 5, 2, 'Leaf3' union all
select 6, 3, 'LeafX';

with Parents
as
(
    select T.RowId, 0 as Depth from @Temp as T where T.ParentId is null
    union all
    select T.RowId, P.Depth + 1
    from Parents as P
        inner join @Temp as T on T.ParentId = P.RowId
)
select T.Name
from Parents as P
    outer apply (select TT.Depth from Parents as TT where TT.RowId = 6) as CALC
    left outer join @Temp as T on T.RowId = P.RowId
where P.Depth = CALC.Depth - 1
```

Comment: this does not work, it finds the wrong level with different test data. Try 'select 6, 3, 'aLeafX'union all
    select 7, 6, 'LeafX';'

Comment: it does work, it finds all data with depth = depth of pointed node - 1

Comment: I appologize, you are using rowid and not name to identify the row, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table(rowid int, parentid int, name varchar(10))
insert @t values(1,NULL,'Level1')
insert @t values(2,NULL,'Level2')
insert @t values(3,1,'Leaf1')
insert @t values(4,1,'Leaf2')
insert @t values(5,2,'Leaf1')
insert @t values(6,3,'LeafX')

;with a as
(
select rowid, parentid, 0 level from @t where name = 'leafx'
union all
select t.rowid, t.parentid, level + 1 from @t t
join a on a.parentid = t.rowid
), b as
(
select rowid, parentid,name,  0 level from @t where parentid is null
union all
select t.rowid, t.parentid,t.name, level + 1 
from b join @t t on b.rowid = t.parentid
)
select rowid, parentid, name from b
where level = (select max(level)-1 from a)

rowid   parentid    name
5   2   Leaf1
3   1   Leaf1
4   1   Leaf2
```

Comment: someone downvoted my answer. My answer finds the siblings of the ancestors of leafx like described in the question. I was tempted to downvote the other 2 answers because they didn't. I added testdata and result to prove my answer works

Comment: i queried your answer, it should return 3-Leaf1, 4-Leaf2, and 5-Leaf1.

Comment: @MartinOngtangco I see your point, going to rewrite the query

Comment: @MartinOngtangco `5-Leaf1` is not a sibling to `3-Leaf1, 4-Leaf2`. They don't have the same parent so they are not siblings. You probably mean that you want all nodes that is on the same level as the parent of `LeafX`. If that is the case I suggest that you update your question.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - No difference in cost for execution plans. I do however think that mine is a bit prettier :) +1.